# Android open PDF : File not found

Tags: android, file, pdf

I try to open a PDF in my application.
First, I create the PDF like that :

```
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/mypdf.pdf";
File file = new File(filename);

try {
    FileOutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bos.write(Base64.decode(base64, 0));
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOError with PDF");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, PdfActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("file", filename);
startActivity(intent);
```

The file is well created and readable, I can open this with ESExplorer application.
This file is located in `/storage/emulated/0/myfile.pdf`

in the PdfActivity I try to open the PDF  :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String url = extras.getString("file");

File file = new File(url);
try {
    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(objIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File NotFound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`file.exists()` return true, Intent start, but my PDF reader says : "File not found"
I've added read and write permissions on external storage.

Does someone have any idea why it can't access to my file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 objIntent.setDataAndType(url, "application/pdf");
```

use above line in your second snippest also declare **String url** as a **global variable** hope it will help you if it will not work try to use hardcode value of file path and see is it working or not ?

and are you sure file is exist? check this scenario tooo :)

Comment: This solution doesn't work because the first argument must be a URI. I've try to load PDF with : Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/myfile.pdf"); put I get the same result.

Comment: The file exists, if I delete it it's re-created and I can open the PDF with Adobe application.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I've replace the Uri like that:

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

And it works!